Spark SQL - performance degradation after adding a new column
My code is in Scala and I'm using Spark SQL syntax to make a union between 3 dataframes of data.
Currently I am working on adding a new field. It's applicable only for one of the dataframes, so the syntax looks like this:
SELECT ..., new_field FROM
(
SELECT ..., new_field FROM A
UNION
SELECT ..., 0 as new_field FROM B
UNION
SELECT ..., 0 as new_field FROM C
)

When I deployed the changed code (I'm using EMR to run it), the performance decreased dramatically - execution time is longer by 50%. I don't see any clear indicator of the issue in Spark GUI.

I had a similar situation when adding another new field in the past, but back then I resolved it by changing the syntax from new_field to coalesce(new_field, 0). This trick doesn't work this time.
I didn't add any join - the field is already used in another column.
I have a suspicion that I'm hitting some internal limit of a Spark row size. It's because if I remove another field with type double from the picture, my issue disappears.

Does anyone have an idea what else I can try? And does my suspicion make any sense?
(I cannot share the exact code or SQL plan).

can you please add input & expected output
